Earth protection in PV + battery system
I'm building a system that looks like this:
PV -> solar charger (48 V) -> batteries (48 V) -> isolated DC/DC (48 V->12 V) -> non isolated DC/DC (12 V->3 V) -> load
The PV's are on a roof, the solar charger on a wall and the rest of the system is supposed to be in a big cabinet.
I want the cabinet to be earth protected. So I figure, I need a GFCI/RCBO/RCD. The most obvious choice would be to put it between the PV and the solar charger, because this domain has the highest voltage and lowest current, but if there is ground leakage, the battery is still powering the load. Is my supposition that I need another one between the battery and isolated DC/DC converter correct?
Additionally, if there is an earth circuit breaker close to the battery, and there is an earth fault on the other side of the isolated DC/DC converter, I expect the earth circuit breaker to not see this, since they are electrically disconnected. Is this the case?
I want this system to be safe to use, and break all power (as good as possible since it's still batteries) if there is any earth leakage sensed. Does anyone have any ideas on how to build this?


Draw a block diagram/schematics, avoid using abbreviations ,...for example SC - does it mean short circuit?

Thanks, edited.

+1 For the edit - far better now.
IMO this is still low voltage setup, unless it is in wet environment you don't need GFCI/RCD but however you need fuses - at least two on the battery for dc/dc converter and charger.
As this setup is a floating, then no leak should occur to the earth, but you have to read carefully the manual of the PV charger. Some they have a positive common (in most cases) others have negative common. If you ground a potential then you won't have a floating setup anymore. Grounding some components may result into a malfunction or even short circuit. So first step is to study the PV charger (positive common, negative common)
High voltage PV arrays are left floating, since the PV cells suffer kind of "cancer" if bonded to a earth potential. Maybe you better leave it floating.

Thanks for the reply. Yes, it is still low voltage setup. However, the plan is to run up to  240A through the system with multiple dc/dc converters in parallel as well as loads. So if anything goes wrong, it can go very wrong. That is why I'm looking into how to protect the system as good as possible.
The solar charger itself is a VarioString VS 120A, which seems to be negative common.

@user362085 Follow the inverter instructions, place fuses, use propriate wire cross sections. A RCBO for such purpose would cost several k$, if exists.
